# The meaning of "late" in "the late Buddy Holly"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, adjective-phrases

I came across an expression "the late Buddy Holly" and additionally gathered two more examples of it, all of which I don't understand.

> The rock 'n roll revival has provoked the Record Industry Assn. of America to award two records by **the late Buddy Holly** for Gold Records.

> Here's one of two previously unreleased sides which find **the late Buddy Holly** working with the swinging tenor man, King Curtis.

> Lead singer Freddie Garrity bore something of visual resemblance to **the late Buddy Holly**, with similar big black eyeglasses and a skinny frame.

I googled who Buddy Holly was, I worked out "the late" is likely to be referring to his occupation, as in *the singer Robert Smith* or *the painter van Gogh*. But I still can't figure out what this profession is.

- Could it mean a ***late**-night (talk show) host*?
- Could it refer to a younger-generation artist whose style resembles Buddy Holly's?
- Could it mean *the **deceased** Buddy Holly*?

Comment: This format wouldn't often be used many decades after someone's death. The reason you find quite a few instances for Buddy Holly is because of the unusual circumstances / timing of his death. So in a way, OP was on the right track thinking ***the late X*** here is similar to ***the artist Y, the painter Z***. The point being there's a strong implication that "identifier" *(late, artist, painter)* represents a ***primary characteristic*** of the referent (or "relevant" attribute, if someone *recently* died). And sadly, Buddy Holly is remembered by some as much for his death as for his music.

Comment: There is tact at work too. At a gathering, someone who does not know that their friend "Buddy" is dead, or perhaps a child, when asking "Where is Buddy" might be told "Buddy is ... late" because it is the wrong moment to tell the truth.

Comment: @WeatherVane Surely the usage _the late Mr. X_ or _her late husband_ is very well-established. I've never heard a deceased person described as 'being late' except in the "No. 1 Ladies Detective Agency" novels!

Comment: @KateBunting indeed it is, but I have often wondered how it came about.

Comment: @WeatherVane https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384034/origin-of-the-usage-of-late-to-mean-deceased

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The late" in these cases does not refer to his occupation -- unless, of course, you consider "no longer being alive" an occupation. "The late Buddy Holly" means "Buddy Holly (who is dead)", only phrased in a more respectful way.

Comment: "Come now or you will be late!" "What for?" "Late, as in the _late Arthur Dent!_ It's a sort of threat, you see..."